# AJAX PUT request to Phillips Hue Hub Local

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, philips-hue

I have created a file with the following:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
<div>
<button type="submit">Turn Light on</button>
</div>
</form>
<script> $('#myForm').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url:'http://192.168.1.102/api/user/lights/1/state',
    type:'PUT',
    data: JSON.stringify({"on":true}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    failure: function(errMsg) {
    alert(errMsg);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Currently, no error or success message is displayed and the light does not turn on. I can only put it down to there being an error in my code, or am I misunderstanding Jquery & AJAX and they are not client side, hence why this doesn't work?

EDIT: Typo on the form ID was the issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I run that code (substituting the IP address of my Hue hub) it alerts an object and the response shows `[{"error":{"type":1,"address":"/lights","description":"unauthorized user"}}]` in the Network tab of my developer tools. (Well, not quite that code. I loaded jQuery too … but if I didn't then trying to use `$` would have thrown a reference error).

Comment: @Quentin Typo on my form ID, it now works.

Comment: is `failure` a callback hook? I think its `error`- might help you debug error messages in the future. From the doc "The beforeSend, error, dataFilter, success and complete options all accept callback functions that are invoked at the appropriate times." http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/